# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined

Tags: jquery, yii

I am trying to style the gridview with bootstrap;

I changed the container tag from `div` tag to `table` tag.

My `cgridview` crashes;

The error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined`

was encountered in the file `jquery.ba-bbq.js`:

`matches = url.match( is_fragment ? /^([^#]*)\#?(.*)$/ : /^([^#?]*)\??([^#]*)(#?.*)/ );`

on the `cgridview`:

```
<div style="padding:5px;">
    <div class="widget widget-4">
        <div class="widget-head">
            <h4 class="heading">Manage Orders</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body">
            <?php
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'id' => 'orders-grid',
                'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
                'filter' => $model,
                'tagName' => 'table',
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'class' => 'table',
                    'style' => 'width:auto;',
                    'align' => 'center',
                ),
                'template' =>
                '<tr><td>{pager}</td></tr>' .
                '<tr><td>{summary}</td></tr>' .
                '<tr><td>{items}</td></tr>' .
                '<tr><td>{summary}</td></tr>' .
                '<tr><td>{pager}</td></tr>',
                'columns' => array(
                    array(
                        'header' => 'Order ID',
                        'name' => 'id',
                        'type' => 'raw',
                        'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->id,array("update","id"=>$data->id))',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'header' => 'Name',
                        'name' => 'var_user_full_name',
                        'value' => '$data->UserFullName',
                        'filter' => CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'var_user_full_name'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'total_price',
                        'type' => 'raw',
                        'value' => '$data->currency." ".$data->total_price',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'created',
                        'header' => 'Created',
                        'type' => 'raw',
                        'value' => 'date("d-m-Y h:i:s", $data->created)',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'active',
                        'header' => 'Status',
                        'value' => 'OrdersData::$active[$data->active]',
                        'filter' => OrdersData::$active,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                        'header' => 'Action',
                        'template' => '{update}',
                    ),
                ),
            ));
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because `url` is `undefined`.

Comment: yes, you were right; post as answer "ticule"; ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error just because `url` is `undefined`.

The problem is somewhere in your JavaScript code. Change the `url`'s value and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check your html tags, if they are properly nested or not.

I was having same issue, and solved (div start & end must be proper.)